# How do you pass an anonymous lambda as an argument in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm stuck on how to pass an anonymous lambda as an argument as in the example below:

```
fun fn_x(x: Int, fn: (Int) -> Int ):Int {
        return fn(x)
}

@Test
{
    assertEquals(3, fn_x(2, ???))
}
```

In place of "???" I tried:

`n->n+1`

`(n)->n+1`

`{n -> n+1}`

Answer (score 1):

Ooops. that was a typo.  This works

```
fun fn_x(x: Int, fn: (Int) -> Int ):Int {
    return fn(x)
}

@Test
fun test1()
{
    assertEquals(3, fn_x(2, {n -> n+1}))
}
```